# Insert Table from Builiding Block in specified location in the word document.

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I want to insert a table which is defined as building block. I placed a content control in specified location in the document and refer to it by "selectcontetcontrolsbytag". Unfortunetly when table is inserted to the conentcontrol, it is convertered to RichText. Here is my code:

```
ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("TermsConditions").Item(1).Range = _
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes.Item(wdTypeTables).Categories.Item("Terms and Conditions Translation").BuildingBlocks.Item("Terms and Conditions Eng")
```

Could you help me with proper code to insert building block in specified location. Also I would like this building block to be replaced by another, when user will select other item from userform, combobox etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "it is converted to Rich Text"...

The accepted way to insert a BuildingBlock is to use the BuildingBlock.Insert method to which you pass the target Range object. For example (based on your code sample):

```
Dim doc as Word.Document
Dim rngTarget as Word.Range
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set rngTarget = doc.SelectContentControlsByTag("TermsConditions").Item(1).Range 
doc.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes.Item(wdTypeTables).Categories.Item("Terms and and Conditions Translation").BuildingBlocks.Item("Terms and Conditions Eng").Insert rngTarget, true
```

Take a look at the example in the VBA Language Reference...

Also, you should not use ThisDocument in your code, use ActiveDocument. (Even better, declare a Document object, assign ActiveDocument to it, then use that.)

Comment: It worked! I am novice in VBA. At the begining I tried insert method, but I tought it can be used only with Selection.Range target. Anyway there is one little flaw in your code which I am currently trying to solve. I can only insert my table once into "termsConditions" content control. I am looking for code to clear/reset/delete/ conent (table in this case!! more tricky, than text) in the content control without removing it. This will allow me to replace one table in the content control with another. Could you help me?

Comment: Does the content control contain only the table, or other things as well? If only the table, make sure the content control's property "Content control cannot be deleted" is activated. Then you should be able to delete the entire ContentControl.Range without deleting the content control.

Comment: Yes it contained one table. I tried your solution. It did not work. I could not remove content when I already placed inside some table. It was protected from deleting too. I found another solution. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Complete solution for my problem is:

1. Solution proposed by Cindy Meister Replacing content inside content
   control:
2. To change content inside content control "TermsConditions"  I added following code:

   If doc.SelectContentControlsByTag("TermsConditions").Item(1).Range.Text <> doc.SelectContentControlsByTag("TermsConditions").Item(1).PlaceholderText Then
   doc.SelectContentControlsByTag("TermsConditions").Item(1).Range.Cut
   Else
   End If

Comment: Your code will execute more efficiently and be easier to read if you declare a variable for an object you re-use frequently and use that. For example: Dim ccTermConditions as Word.ContentControl : Set ccTermConditions = doc.SelectContentControlsByTag.Item(1) : If ccTermConditions.Range.Text <> ccTermConditions.PlaceholderText Then ccTermConditions.Range.Cut : End If    (Since new lines aren't possible in Comments the colons (:) indicate where there'd be a new line in your code.)